# Access Watson NLP Assets through watsonx notebook - getting the project access token

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using Watson NLP for sentiment analysis in a WatsonX notebook. When I go to the Manage tab and select Access Control to create a new access token under Access Tokens, I get a "No project access token" message. Also, upon checking the settings page, I'm unsure where to find or generate this token. Has anyone faced this problem or can offer guidance on how to resolve it?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

I followed the instructions provided here (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/watsonx-as-a-service?topic=notebook-manually-adding-project-access-token), but I'm encountering an issue.